# How can I change the line height in the Xfce4 interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, xubuntu, xfce4, gtk3

I have been looking for ways to change(reduce) the line height or padding top/bottom on all lines in the X interface. Xubuntu 18.04 LTS
[image: example Thunar]

After many searches, I have found that I have to edit the ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css file. However, the file does not exist by default, and I do not know what elements/widgets to add/enter.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html

Comment: You can try to ask [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewforum.php?id=4)